# Sending image file in POST request using Axios on React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, post, file-upload, axios

I am trying to send an image file using Axios and keep getting `AxiosError: Network Error`.
I have figured out that the POST request does not get initiated in the first place, which seems to point towards an issue with the payload I am sending.

Here is my frontend upload handler. It uses `expo-image-picker`:

```
const _handleImagePicked = async (imageData) => {
        try {
            setUploading(true);
    
            if (!imageData.cancelled) {
                const responseData = await uploadImage(imageData);
                props.navigation.navigate('Result', { result: responseData.result });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            alert('Image upload failed:(');
        } finally {
            setUploading(false);
        }
    };
```

And here is my apiService that contains the uploadImage() function used above. It uses `axios`:

```
export const uploadImage = async (imageData) => {
    try {
        const formData = new FormData();
        uri = imageData.assets[0].uri
        const fileExtension = uri.split('.').pop() || 'jpeg';

        formData.append('image', {
            uri: uri,
            name: `image.${fileExtension}`,
            type: `image/jpeg`,
        });
        
        const apiResponse = await axios.post(API_ENDPOINT, formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
        });
        
        const responseData = apiResponse.data;
        //console.log(responseData)
        return responseData;

    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
```

When I console log the imageData, this is what I get:

`{"assets": [{"assetId": null, "base64": null, "duration": null, "exif": null, "height": 810, "rotation": null, "type": "image", "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2560anonymous%251Ffe_mob_medtech-2cda528f-188f-410b-a97c-24fc38b94a54/ImagePicker/ffa7e7e6-e8c0-4f5e-82c3-b519914a379d.jpeg", "width": 1080}], "canceled": false, "cancelled": false}`

When I console log uri (i.e. imageData.assets[0].uri):

`file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2560anonymous%251Ffe_mob_medtech-2cda528f-188f-410b-a97c-24fc38b94c54/ImagePicker/ffa7e7e6-e8a0-4f5e-82c3-b519914a379d.jpeg`

I also console logged the blob from the uri, and this is what I got:

`{"_data": {"__collector": {}, "blobId": "a38f48c9-2a2b-443b-8088-3cbf1fa5109a", "lastModified": 0, "name": "ffa8e7e6-e8c0-4f5e-82c3-b519914a379d.jpeg", "offset": 0, "size": 22779, "type": "image/jpeg"}}`

My API endpoint expects formData with a Key called 'image' and a Value which is the image itsef.

Now my issue is that I have tried to pass imageData, uri, or the the blob in the formData and it gives the same error each time. Can you let me know where I am going wrong in terms of the payload I am sending?